# External Voronoi library "Mesh": What is Sketch and Processing?

Tags: java, processing, libraries, voronoi

## Question

This might be a too specific quesion but I figured I'd give it a shot. If it doesn't belong here, I apologize.

I've been looking for an external library that generates a Voronoi Diagram with edges and Regions.

I've had a look at [simplevoronoi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplevoronoi/) but it doesn't calculate regions so I figuered I'd continue looking.

I found [Mesh](http://leebyron.com/else/mesh/) made by Lee Bryon and I've tried to use it just like any other external library but it does produce an exception at compile time

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: processing/core/PApplet
    at megamu.mesh.IntArray.add(IntArray.java:21)
    at megamu.mesh.Voronoi.<init>(Voronoi.java:88)
```

On the website the install guide reads

```
Install
    Download Mesh
    Unzip into Processing's libraries folder
    Sketch → Import Library → mesh
```

Now my questions are: What is Processing? What is Sketch? And will I be able to use this library in my project somehow or can someone recommend a different one?

## Solution (kind of)

In the end I tried to use a library called [Java Power Voronoi Diagram](https://github.com/ArlindNocaj/power-voronoi-diagram) made by [Arlind Nocaj](https://github.com/ArlindNocaj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing is an environment/language which is based on Java. You can find more information about it here: http://processing.org/

As far as getting that library working, it might be fairly simple to port it. Processing's syntax is nearly identical to Java's. You'll have to make proper Java classes for everything if that hasn't already been done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried porting it but in the end I just went with a different library called [Java Power Voronoi Diagram](https://github.com/ArlindNocaj/power-voronoi-diagram) made by [Arlind Nocaj](https://github.com/ArlindNocaj).

Answer (score 0):

you can quickly generate a voronoi diagram in **Processing** (Development Environment) using a library called **toxi**. Here is an example, https://github.com/hamzeen/voronoi_image

P.S. Processing is a tiny development environment specially for artists (yet not restricted to them) to quickly prototype their ideas with minimal code (java) & it's based on java applets.